# how to make a label in the desired position?

Tags: javascript, php, html, label, navbar

I want to make a notification bar and add some label on that, but the label does not get in position as I wanted.

how can I fix it?

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown nav-user">
 <a class="nav-link nav-user-img" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="fa fa-envelope" style="color: #82849f"></span> &nbsp <span class="navbarDropdownMenuLink2 fa fa-sort-down" style="color: #82849f"></span 
 </a>
 <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right nav-user-dropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink3">
  <ul class="dropdown-item" style="list-style: none;">           
   <?php foreach($total as $t){
    $tot = $t->total;
    if($tot != 0){
     echo '<span class="label label-pill label-danger count" style="border-radius:10px;">';
     echo $t->total;
     echo '</span>';
    }else{
     echo ' ';
    }                        
    }?>
```

Comment: Could you tell us what is the desired position?

Comment: in top of the envelope, but not far

Comment: can i have your email address, because i can't show you the image

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
Please add more details of the issue you are facing, e.g. add a working live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://jsfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/)